# Dropwizard log to endpoint

Tags: logging, dropwizard

I want dropwizard to log to a endpoint.

Getting dropwizard to log to a file is easy i.e in the config you just specify type as file and currentLogfilename.

But how do you get dropwizard to log to an http endpoint?

i.e

```
http://x.x.x.x:9181/LogService?level=info&message=dropwizardmessage
```

Comment: I am also in the dark on this. In my scenario I am trying to send my dropwizard logs to graylog.

Comment: Dropwizard has a tcp socket appender: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-logging/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/logging/TcpSocketAppenderFactory.java would this help?

Answer (score 0):

My observation is, I have configured the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>metrics-servlets</artifactId>
    <version>${metrics.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

i am able to get the metrics on http-endpoint

http://localhost:adminport/metrics